# C# registering for an event via constructor

Tags: c#, events, constructor

I've got a class which is generating an event.
Normally I register with `this.obj.testEvent += new oClass.LogHandler(handleIt);`

The class oClass has a property containing an instance of another class.
`public class oClass
    {
        public qClass qclassobj;
    }`

And qClass has a property containing an instance of pClass etc.

When I create an instance of oClass, the other classes are also created.

Is it possible to register recursively to all the events (which do have to same name and attributes) by passing a parameter via the constructor or something like that?
So that ever ytime the `testEvent` is generated in one of the classes the `handleIt` function is called.

I hope you understand my question, any help appreciated :)

KR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass it in using a delegate:

```
class RootClass
{
    public event EventHandler<ResolveEventArgs> Resolve;

    public RootClass() { }

    public RootClass(EventHandler<ResolveEventArgs> resolve)
    {
        if (resolve != null)
            Resolve += resolve;
    }
}

class InheritedClass : RootClass
{
    public InheritedClass() { }

    public InheritedClass(EventHandler<ResolveEventArgs> resolve)
        : base(resolve) // Is this what you are looking for?
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure, can you provide an example how to create an instance of the RootClass? Thanks

Comment: @Mark `new RootClass(handleIt)`.

Comment: Getting this: `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.EventHandler<System.ResolveEventArgs>'`

Comment: @Mark you will need to actually figure out what delegate type the event is. Notice how `EventHandler<ResolveEventArgs>` in the constructor matches the one in `public event...`. If you are using Visual Studio just hit F12 on `testEvent` to see what type of delegate it is.

Comment: Thanks I got that. It is not possible to generate the event inside the `InheritedClass` it says: `The event 'bla.RootClass.Resolve' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'bla.RootClass')` but it works fine to have a method doing : `this.Resolve(this, new EventArgs());` in the RootClass.

Comment: @Mark you should really be reading C# tutorials. You can't invoke it from an inherited class - but what you can do is define a protected method on the base class that invokes it. E.g. `protected void OnHandleIt(EventArgs e) { Resolve(this, new EventArgs()); }` then in your inherited class you can invoke the event via `OnHandleIt(new EventArgs());`.

Comment: Ye I made it work and it looks perfect! Thanks for your help bud!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your C# endeavours.